# How to Make Geth 1.9+ Full Node to Trace Ancient Blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, state-trie-pruning, transaction-trace

I have full-synced a Geth 1.9.9 node but my requests including ancient blocks erroring. I know this is because of state-pruning but I wonder how to enable tracing for an ancient block so it returns the result instead of an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run an archive node, rather than just a full one.  Use `--gcmode archive` command line option.  See [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for details.

Comment: I can't because of storage costs. I want tracer to tracer it on the fly.

Comment: In order to trace a transaction one needs to have blockchain state as it was right before the transaction, so to be able to trace arbitrary ancient transactions you need to have the whole history of blockchain states.  This is what archive node does.

Comment: Not true. You can trace older blocks with a full node. By default, it traces the last 128 nodes.

Comment: The question was about ancient blocks.

Comment: Yeah, block 6000000 is ancient for me.

Comment: how do you trace older blocks @ferit

Comment: :) That's what I'm asking @relik